# Create v3 gitolite repositories from existing v2 repos

Tags: gitolite

I have got a gitolite v2 installed on my company's server, and now I have to administrate it. Since it's really chaotic there I decided to install a new one, now it's v3. I have around 8 repositories what I want to move to the new install.

I don't need the old .rc file or any configurations, just the (working!) `$GIT_HOME/repositories/*.git`

**What I tried:** (found it while searching for solution)
copied all `$GIT_OLD_HOME/repositories/*.git` to `$GIT_HOME/repositories/*.git` (except gitolite-admin.git and testing.git)

then I updated the `gitolite-admin.git/conf/gitolite.conf` (by cloning and pushing back changes) with this kind of entries:

`repo myrepo1`
`RW+   =  @all`

Now if I want to clone anything other than gitolite-admin or testing, it sais:
`FATAL: R any myrepo1 myusername DENIED by fallthru`

**Few things I've checked:**
`ls -l $GIT_HOME` -> gitolite:gitolite it's ok I guess since gitolite is the user I want to use
I did the same for all entries in the `repositories` directory and the permissions are the same.

I was googling for a solution however I didn't find any that fits my case. If you can help me or suggest me anything, please don't hold back :)

If you need any more details to find out the answer just tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have migrated your [`.gitolite.rc` file](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/rc.html), as described in the **[g2->g3 migration page](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/migr.html)**

> if you're migrating from g2, there are some settings that MUST be dealt with before running gitolite setup; please read the migration page and linked pages, and especially the one on "presetting the rc file"
>
> The rc file for g3 is quite different from that of g2.

Or if you don't need the old one, as you mention, make sure the content of the default new one has appropriate values.

Make sure your new `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file does contain a line with `myusername` in it.

---

The [OP Attila Horvath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2190628/attila-horvath) [confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523161/create-v3-gitolite-repositories-from-existing-v2-repos/15523310?noredirect=1#comment21991271_15523310):

> Note: nothing in any of the gitolite `install/setup/etc` will ever touch the data in any repository except the `gitolite-admin` repo. The only thing it will normally touch in normal repos is the update hook."
>
> The last sentence just grabbed my attention, and it seems now that was the problem.
> I first installed gitolite then copied there the repos, **so I had to run again `gitolite setup -pk mykey.pub` and now it seems working**!

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499002/please-help-me-understand-gitolite-users, http://stackoverflow.com/q/12617672/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10843781/6309

Comment: Thank you for your reply VonC! I have an appropriate entry in my `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` like:
  
`# gitolite start  
command=... mypubkey  
# gitolite end`

Comment: Also I've checked the official migration page before, but I think I did everything well, since I don't need previous configurations or the .rc file.

Comment: @AttilaHorvath does your entry contains 'myusername'?  as in `command="/home/git/bin/gitolite-shell myusername",no-port-forwarding,...` g3 should use `gitolite-shell`.

Comment: Yes, it does, but there is a little difference. Here is mine: `command="$GIT_HOME/src/gitolite-shell myusername",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty` 

I have a bin directory in $GIT_HOME, but it contains only gitolite.

Comment: How dumb I am! "Note: nothing in any of the gitolite install/setup/etc will ever touch the data in any repository except the gitolite-admin repo. The only thing it will normally touch in normal repos is the update hook."
The last sentence just grabbed my attention, and it seems now that was the problem. I **first** installed gitolite **then** copied there the repos, so I had to run again `gitolite setup -pk mykey.pub` and now it seems working! Thank you @VonC for your help!

Comment: @AttilaHorvath great! I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and upgrading did not work as it should so I used the following strategy - the bold text represents where was the step executed:

1- **New:** Install Gitolite (https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite).

2- **Workstation:** In a new empty directory clone the gitolite-admin of the old version and rename it to `gitolite-admin-old`. Remove access to all users in gitolite-admin-old/conf/gitolite.conf except yourself - To disable anyone to do any change while you are migrating the repositories.

3- **Workstation:** Clone all repositories from the old Gitolite. `git clone git@oldserver.com:repo`.

4- **Old:** We already got what we want from the old repository. Disable old gitolite for good by adding `exit 0` at the top of `.gitolite.rc` file.

5- **Workstation:** Clone gitolite-admin from the new server `git clone git@newserver.com:gitolite-admin gitolite-admin-new`

6- **Workstation:** Copy keys from the `gitolite-admin-old/keydir` to the `gitolite-admin-new/keydir`, add the repositories you want to transfer in the new `gitolite-admin-new/conf/gitolite.conf` with the user priviledges. add, commit and push.

7- **Workstation:** Push each required repository to the new server

```
git push --all git@newserver.com:repo
git push --tags git@newserver.com:repo
or
git push --mirror git@newserver.com:repo
```

8- **Workstations:** Change DNS or remote URL from each working repo.

Hope this helps

Comment: Interesting workaround (if my own answer doesn't work for you). +1